# How to extract column data from csv file using shell command

Tags: shell, command

I have the following CSV file as input

```
sample1 compute.googleapis.com/projects/project_ID1/zones/europe-west2-a test1
sample1 compute.googleapis.com/projects/project_ID2/zones/europe-west2-a test2
sample1 compute.googleapis.com/projects/project_ID3/zones/europe-west2-a test3
```

How I can use a shell command to  extract project ID from column 2 of the above file and save it as CSV as shown below
enter code here

```
sample1 project_ID1 test1
sample1 project_ID2 test2
sample1 project_ID3 test3
```

Thanks
Ajit

Comment: If i am not wrong csv is a comma separated file , Output shown in question is not ended with comma after each record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit of modification to above @Arkadiusz Drabczyk solution would give comma separated data

**Code :**

```
awk -F '[/ ]' '{print $1 "," $4 "," $7}' demo.txt
```

**Expected Output :**

```
sample1,project_ID1,test1
sample1,project_ID2,test2
sample1,project_ID3,test3
```

**You can write the above data to new file using below command**

```
awk -F '[/ ]' '{print $1 "," $4 "," $7}' demo.txt >> demo.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Wit awk:

```
$ awk -F '[/ ]' '{print $1, $4, $7}' FILE
sample1 project_ID1 test1
sample1 project_ID2 test2
sample1 project_ID3 test3
```